# Guardar campo da tabela em uma variável em php

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

Boa tarde gente, tudo bem com vocês?
Eu tenho uma duvida básica, mas creio que vocês poderiam me ajudar, como eu poderia guardar o resultado de um campo dentro de uma variável em PHP?

`$sql = "SELECT ped_liberado FROM tb_pedido WHERE ped_id = 1267570";`

Essa é minha SELECT, eu gostaria de guardar o valor do campo 'ped_liberado', como eu poderia guardar isso dentro de uma variável?

Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digamos que esta usando postgresql:

```
$sql = "SELECT ped_liberado FROM tb_pedido WHERE ped_id = 1267570";
$resultado = pg_query($sql);
$ped_liberado = pg_fetch_result($resultado,0,"ped_liberado ");
```

Comment: Beleza, muito obrigado Gabriel, to fazendo vários testes aqui, forte abraço.

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver usando PDO, seria mais ou menos assim:

```
$conn = funcao_de_conexao();
$sql = "SELECT ped_liberado FROM tb_pedido WHERE ped_id = 1267570";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $query->execute();
$id_pedido = $query->fetchColumn(); // vai trazer o único resultado e armazenar na variavel
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Andre pela ajuda, to realizando vários testes aqui para ver com qual eu acabo por utilizar, forte abraço.

Comment: De nada e boa sorte, qualquer coisa, pode perguntar!